# How can I have one "master" domain redirect to other domains based on the visitors country?

Tags: 301-redirect, geolocation

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to purchase one "master" domain but make its sole purpose to redirect and fork visitors to country specific external domains. Sounds confusing, but here is an example of what I mean:

I buy domain `ABCXYZ.com`, if someone from USA visits this "master" domain, it redirects them to `abcxzy.shopify.com`. If someone from Canada visits the master domain then they are redirected to `randomcanadasite.com`.

Everything I could find only talks about using subdomains so having `us.abcxyz.com` and `ca.abcxyz.com`.

I know there are also CDNs but my understanding is that they only show the content you host on a single domain.

Basically I am trying to find a way to buy one domain and have geo-location filtered traffic be redirected to "unrelated" domains. How can I do this?

Comment: You would need to redirect visitors using a Geolocation database based on IP address (aka, a GeoIP database) for each country you intended on targeting. This can be done via server-side scripting or using a JavaScript API (see [this](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/) for code examples). First you need to identify the country based on the IP lookup, then you can redirect the visitor to whatever domain you chose. As to how to code this, unfortunately [coding](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is considered off-topic here and would really depend on what language you'd like to use.

Comment: How would anybody ever know to visit this domain to get redirected?   In the case of sub-domains, you need something for when people take the sub-domain off of their country site.   However, a master domain cannot be derived from other domain sites.

Answer (score 3):

Redirecting based on location can be error-prone and is considered user-*un*friendly in most cases, but if that's what you want to do:

1. Set up some type of web server [(nginx, apache, etc.)](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+server+software&oq=web+server).
2. On that web server, implement redirects to other domains (whether it's an entirely different domain or a subdomain doesn't matter) based on IP address.
3. Point your domain name to that web server with a new "A Record."

Comment: It's unnecessary to ask for the location permission if you're targeting a user with rough country-level accuracy. You can just geolocate their IP.

Comment: @Maximillian Laumeister You are correct -- I've removed that sentence. Not sure what assumption I made so many months ago, but it definitely wasn't accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,  you are trying to redirect visitors to country-specified domain URLs based on visitors, is that correct?

If so, the first thing you need to know is that you need to purchase multiple domains URLs including all different country-specified URL domains.

To redirect visitors to country-specific URLs, IP geolocations technology is a solution. It detects your visitors country based on IP. "The super domain" you mentioned could be potentially be a generated short URL link. For example,some tools GEO location tools can generate such short URLs. Once a visitor click on the link, it will redirect visitors to correct URLs accordingly. You can simply create redirecting rules, each rule defines the targeted region, and its associated URL. Thus, visitors from different locations can only view pages relevant to them, and increase customer conversion rate.

Comment: No need to purchase multiple domains. Typically subdomains are also an option, but it seems like op already has his redirect targets figured out.